# How can I copy guides to another page that has different orientation? (e.g. Left to Right)

Tags: adobe-indesign, guides

This sounds really simple, but I'm so stuck I'm needing some help here to think about this.

I'm creating a book kind of document and needed guides for my Master Pages, so I started making them on a left page, and then wanted to copy it to the right one so they could be on the same place but both on the left and right types of pages.

I guess I could make the guides as spread guides, but since I want to make this as Master Page guides, I need them to be page guides only because I wanna be able to use them on just one side some parts of my document. I actually have no idea if spread guides on master pages when they are only aplied to one page of a spread still work as spread guides or just keep it on the page it was aplied.

This is my first question here, English is not my first language so I'm sorry it this is confusing... I'll try my best to explain it better if that's the case! To be fair this sounds more like a confusion on my mind, but I'm really stuck here so I decided to call for help. I've been thinking about this for some time now and it gets me so mad because it looks so easy to solve but I still can't get it!

[image: My left page with the guides I want to copy to the right one]

Thank you so much for the help in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the way I would approach this is by adding guide lines around the page edges. With those you can position the guides accurately when copying.
If you need to mirror them as well I think there is no other way than to rebuild them (either with some math and numeric positioning or with rectangle as spacing guides)

Comment: Mirroring!! That's the perfect word I needed, thank you so much. I've been working on my project rebuilding the guides (mostly copying them and changing the x axis so they can appear on the right page) but I was still wondering if there was a way to make this easy. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key when dragging out a guide.

That will force the guide extend across *both* pages.

[image]

Note that holding the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down, while dragging a guide out, will toggle between a horizontal/vertical guide.

---

You **can** also copy/paste guides between pages.

- Ensure `View > Guides & Grids > Lock Guides` is **not** checked.
- Using the **Selection Tool** (Black arrow)
- Select the guides and choose `Edit > Copy` from the menu
- Move to another page and choose `Edit > Paste in Place`

This will paste the guides in the same place on the new page.

The most challenging part of this is actually selecting the guides. It can be helpful to hide the visibility of all artwork first. You can utilize the **Layers Panel** to leave the layer itself *visible*, but expand it and turn off visibility for everything the layer contains. Only guides should remain visible (and selectable).

Comment: Thank you so much! That really does the job, but I wanted to know when there's a one page only guide that I want to copy to the other page :) I don't want to use spread guides on master pages because sometimes I'll just use one side of it. Hope it does make sense!

Comment: Updated answer @digitalsloth